# Passing variable with double quotes to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, string, codeigniter

In my controller, I have a string coming from database. I use

```
$user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');

$this->load->model('database','', TRUE);

$projects = $this->database->get_projects($user_id);

    foreach($projects as $project)
    {

        echo '  <div onclick="someFunction(\''.$project['description'].'\')"></div>';
    }
```

to pass value to a Javascript. 
Everything works fine, unless there's a double quote in the string. Firebug throws

> unterminated string literal

I've tried:

```
onclick = "someFunction(\''.addslashes($project['description']).'\')"
```

or

```
$description = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $project['description']);
onclick = "someFunction(\''.$description.'\')";
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
onclick = someFunction(<?php echo '"'.$myVariable.'"'; ?>);
```

You can't quote the parenthesis of the arguments... that's global, not only applicable for JS.

For mixin up PHP with js or html, just use the echo wherever you need to. Or google for the MVC model if you want cleaner code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using codeIgniter and I do use an echo for creating the div. Looks like echo ' <div onclick="someFunction(\''.addslashes($project['description']).'\')">

Comment: dunno if  a type in your comment but you have a single quote missing at the end of your string then (the closing singlequote after >.

If it's not that you should include codeigniter in your question's title or tag as for example, I have no idea of codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you could do is to create a view containing this code:

```
<div onclick="someFunction('<?php echo $project['description'] ?>')"></div>
```

and call it in your controller. Eventually you can use the php function [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) to quote strings/characters.

If you need to store this html in a variable in your controller, you can simply use the third parameter calling the view; it's explained [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#footer).

Update:
Try using [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/it/function.htmlentities.php) and not addslashes

Comment: I've used addslashes (see question), but this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: try using htmlentities() and not addslashes